# Angular is not Reloading component when routerLink clicked

Tags: angular, angular6, angular2-routing

I am not able to reload the component when i call click event. I tried the following code

```
 (dealCode,periodName) => {

    let url:any='/valuation;dealcode=J9PPR;fundPeriod=2019Q3;useDefault=true';
    this.router.navigateByUrl('/dummy', { skipLocationChange: true });
    setTimeout(() =>this.router.navigate([url]));
  }
```

Comment: That is native functionality. Angular will not reload a component unless the data feeding it changes (`@Input`) or a uri / route param is updated to a new value.

Answer (score 0):

Angular is doing a url encode, you have to tell him to trust you

```
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';
constructor(
    private _sanitzer: DomSanitizer
) { }
```

Your function

```
(dealCode,periodName) => {

    let url:any='/valuation;dealcode=J9PPR;fundPeriod=2019Q3;useDefault=true';
    this.router.navigateByUrl('/dummy', { skipLocationChange: true });
    const safeUrl = this._sanitzer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(url);

    setTimeout(() =>this.router.navigate([safeUrl]));
  }
```